# Monitoring JMS queues in WAS

Tags: jms, websphere, jmx

Little bit of backgroud: I need to improve the performance of one of our batch framework. There, batch inputs are sent to a JMS queue. Further, at the queue endpoint, we have a MDB, which is consuming the messages. Now, what i suspect here that if there are large number of messages, there is no MDB instance available to consume the messages as all of them are held up in processing the previous messages. To improve this, i am thinking of implementing a threadpool in the MDB business logic so that once the MDB has received the message and deliver it to the thread, it gets free for consuming another message.

Now before implementing this, i want to monitor my JMS queues to check if the messages are really waiting in the queues or not. So i need to know if this monitoring can be done via some WAS admin console or some JMX application. My main purpose is to check the waiting time of each jms message in the queue.

Comment: Before you start implementing some complex logic you have to know if message order is critical for you, persistent/non-persistent messages can be used. Check current setting on "Maximum concurrent MDB invocations per endpoint", check via PMI how many concurrent MDBs are run and what is onMessage avg response time. You can also play with the "Maximum batch size" setting to check, if it will have any impact.

Comment: @Gas sorry i am not good with the abbreviations. What is this PMI? And yes, order is not important because the messages present in the queue have been put from a flat file by a thread pool which can be in any random order.

Comment: PMI is performance monitoring infrastructure, built in WAS functionality that allows you to monitor various things. Look for more details in the WebSphere Knowledge Center.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can set the number of processes (MDB instances) that will consumes the Q in parallel. The default is 10 (Per member of the cluster..).
With the console: `Resources -> JMS -> activation specifications`, Set `"Maximum concurrent MDB invocations per endpoint"` which is defined as `"The maximum number of endpoints to which messages are delivered concurrently."``

As for monitoring the Q and generating some load, you can have a look at [JMSToolBox on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox)

In the "Destination information" dialog in JMSToolBox, you will also be able to see the number of concurrent consumers on the Q

Also if you want to measure the time spend by a message in the Q, just compute the difference between the current time and the `JMSTimestamp` JMS standard property from the message it is process by the MDB in the `onMessage()` method